# Getting images from Firebase JSON

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was wondering if it were possible to fetch an image from the Firebase Database? I know that I can use the storage but for my particular situation it needs to be altered a lot and would be a lot easier if I could enter in the information into the JSON tree and fetch it that way.

So in short, my question is can I use the URL from the storage section of Firebase and copy and paste that into a child in the JSON tree and retrieve it as I would any other number or string in the database?

Every time I code it out it says trying to unwrap a nil value which means it is not finding the image that the URL is pointing to, I assume.

Thanks in advance. Here is the Fetch code that I am using:

```
let newsimage1 = cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UIImageView
let fetch2 = BASE_URL.child("/AA News Feed 1/Image")
fetch2.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    let base64EncodedString = snapshot.value
    let imageData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64EncodedString as! String,
                options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)
    let decodedImage = UIImage(data:imageData!)!
    newsimage1.image = decodedImage
}, withCancelBlock: { error in
    print(error.description)
})
```

Comment: Give your code, what have you tried. Also FBDB is a realtime Database , you can not store metadata in FBDB . And yes you can do that(actually thats the general approach, to store the image's  Storage navigation path in Database, retrieve it every time you need it./...)

Comment: code posted... I do not need to save any images just need to retrieve different images that i will upload into Firebase

Comment: What line causes the error? You probably want to test if the image exists with `snapshot.exists`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/interface_f_i_r_data_snapshot.html#af14cbacf7ef15cf8c31196bc03e9db09

Comment: The line that errors is the "let decodedImage = uiimage(data:imageData!)!

Comment: I should add that I have been pulling numbers and strings and no how to do that. The image stuff is just all new to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you suggested is generally how you'd retrieve an image from Firebase. You simply store the URL in your `FirebaseDatabase` then use it to retrieve the image from `FirebaseStorage`.

**General Setup**

```
var storageRootRef: FIRStorageReference!
var databaseRootRef: FIRDatabaseReference!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    storageRootRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference()
    databaseRootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
}
```

**Image Saving**

You first need to save the image to `FirebaseStorage` then retrieve the `downloadURL` of its location, then only can you go ahead and write this info into your `FirebaseDatabase` as shown below

*Swift 2*

```
func createUserToDatabase()
{
    storageRootRef = storageRootRef.child("ProfileImages").child(self.currentUser.uid + ".png")

    if let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(currentUser.profileImage)
    {
        storageRootRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata: FIRStorageMetadata?, error: NSError?) in

            if let storageError = error
            {
                print("Firebase Upload Error")
                print(storageError.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            else if let storageMetadata = metadata
            {
                if let imageURL = storageMetadata.downloadURL()
                {
                    self.currentUser.profileImageURL = imageURL.absoluteString
                    // TODO: Now you may write to your Firebase Database since you already have the imageURL stored.
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

*Swift 3*

```
func createUserToDatabase()
{
    storageRootRef = storageRootRef.child("ProfileImages").child(self.currentUser.uid + ".png")

    if let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(currentUser.profileImage)
    {
        storageRootRef.put(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata: FIRStorageMetadata?, error: Error?) in

            if let storageError = error
            {
                print("Firebase Upload Error")
                print(storageError.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            else if let storageMetadata = metadata
            {
                if let imageURL = storageMetadata.downloadURL()
                {
                    self.currentUser.profileImageURL = imageURL.absoluteString
                    // TODO: Now you may write to your Firebase Database since you already have the imageURL stored.
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**Image Retrieval**

Simply query into your `FirebaseDatabase` for the `imageURL`, then initiate a `URLSession` for its retrieval as shown below.

*Swift 2*

```
func retrieveUserData()
{
    databaseRootRef!.child("path").observeSingleEventOfType(
    .Value) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in

        if let firebaseValue = snapshot.value
        {
            self.currentUser.profileImageURL = firebaseValue["profileImageURL"] as! String
        }

        let imageURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: self.currentUser.profileImageURL)!

        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(imageURL, completionHandler: { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) in

            if let sessionError = error
            {
                print("Error Downloading Image")
                print(sessionError.localizedDescription)
            }
            else if let sessionData = data
            {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                    self.currentUser.profileImage = UIImage(data: sessionData)!
                })
            }
        }).resume()
    }
}
```

*Swift 3*

```
func retrieveUserData()
{
    databaseRootRef!.child("path").observeSingleEvent(
    of: .value) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in

        if let firebaseValue = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]
        {
            self.currentUser.profileImageURL = firebaseValue["profileImageURL"] as! String
        }

        let imageURL: URL = URL(string: self.currentUser.profileImageURL)!

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: imageURL, completionHandler: { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

            if let sessionError = error
            {
                print("Error downloading image")
                print(sessionError.localizedDescription)
            }
            else if let sessionData = data
            {
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.currentUser.profileImage = UIImage(data: sessionData)!
                })
            }

        }).resume()
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

1. `FirebaseStorage` no longer allows you to add files directly into the root so it's advisable to create directories instead to store your images in. For unique purposes, your image names can be of format `var imageName: String = NSUUID().UUIDString + ".png"` or you could do what I did which was `var imageName: String = userUID + ".png"`.
2. Before uploading, its advisable to compress your images first for faster queries and retrievals.