# Images fetched from firebase are duplicated in the process of adding them to tableViewCells?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The following code fetches images from firebase, but incorrectly duplicates two images. I think that is due to the placement of the `self.tableView.reloadData()` None of the placements I've tried work. Can anyone give me suggestions?

```
    func fetchAllUsersImages() {
    print("inside func")
    self.ref.child("Posts").child(self.userID).child(self.postNum).observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        if let snapShotValue = snapshot.value as? [String: String] {
            for (_, value) in snapShotValue {
                if let imageURL = URL(string: value) {
                    print(imageURL, "image url here")
                    do {
                        let imageAsData = try Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
                        let image = UIImage(data: imageAsData)
                        let ImageObject = Image()
                        ImageObject.image = image
                        self.arrayOfImgObj.append(ImageObject)
                    } catch {
                        print("imageURL was not able to be converted into data")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: you may find a solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39597844/getting-images-from-firebase-json?rq=1

Comment: @Usama no that does not answer teh question

Comment: in the proposed solution he have retrieved images from firebase.

Comment: @Usama I already do that, the problem is that the images when added to teh cells are being duplicated. And I believ tahts due to teh placement of self.tableView.reloadData() wich is not in teh code above because im wondering where it shoudl eb polaced to avaoid this, originaly it was in eth do block

Comment: @TheGreatVisionary Don't reply to comments or other answers in the text of the question, reply in comments below your question or below the answers you're responding to. If people see the question they'll assume it may be unanswered if you (the question asker) have not yet clicked the checkmark next to one of the answers to acknowledge it as the accepted answer. (Please do that when someone does provide a working answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you clear the array when start calling the function because you are appending data to the array. Secondly, reload table after finished the for loop.

```
func fetchAllUsersImages() {
    self.arrayOfImgObj.removeAll() // clean the array

    self.ref.child("Posts").child(self.userID).child(self.postNum).observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        if let snapShotValue = snapshot.value as? [String: String] {
            for (_, value) in snapShotValue {

            }
            tableView.reloadData() // reload view
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: This still duplicated the images... I had two in the specific location and it duplicated both resulting in 4 imageds in the tableView